# Vaadin: Creating an ArrayList of TabSheets

Tags: java, collections, casting, arraylist, vaadin

In Vaadin, I'm creating an Array of TabSheets.

```
    ArrayList<TabSheet> Tabs = new ArrayList<TabSheet>();
```

I perform some operations on them, like adding additional tabs/tabsheets to each of the Tabsheets in the arraylist.

After that, when I try to add it to the mainWindow as a Component, I get an error. This is how I try it:

```
    BaseClassWindow.addComponent((Component) Tabs);
```

I get this ClassCastError:

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.vaadin.ui.Component
```

How can this problem be solved? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You need to put your tabsheets in a container for them to be displayable. How are you expecting them to be shown?

Comment: In Vaadin, once I add them as a Component to the Window Instance, they show up. The problem is, the Casting that occurs here, from an ArrayList instance to a vaadin ui component.

Comment: Yes, that is normal that you are getting a Cast error, you can only display Components, and an ArrayList isn't one. If you only want to display one TabSheet at a time, call `BaseClassWindow.addComponent(Tags.get(the_index_you_want))`.

Comment: You're right, I realize what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An ArrayList is not an Component so you can't cast it. The content of the list, the TabSheets, however is, so you can add those.

For example:

```
for(TabSheet tabsheet : tabs){
  myWindow.addComponent(tabsheet);
}
```